# How to get negative voltage on PWM signal

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, negative-voltage

I'm researching EV charging stations. Looking at the [SAE J1772](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_J1772#Control_Pilot) communication protocol, I see that there is a +12 to -12 volt 1 kHz PWM signal on the control pilot, which indicates the charging station's current capacity when the vehicle is connected.

To get the negative voltage I can use a 12 Vdual voltage power supply, but then my controller outputs a 5 V PWM signal. If I supply that to the gate of a MOSFET and connect 12 V to drain and -12 V to source, I'm not really sure what will happen..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBokiV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically use a level shifter of some kind.

A comparator or op-amp will do here, but there's plenty of other ways too. In simple cases an RS-232 transceiver could work.

The best way to do it is of course application specific to what the standard requires about the signal, such as amplitude tolerance, rise/fall time, bandwidth, output impedance, short-circuit current, etc.